In Excel, in the PivotTable fields List, how can I remove automatically generated month field which Excel has created by grouping a date field?
I am using a PivotTable in Excel on data from a Power Query connection.  When I selected a date field from my data model by dragging it into the Rows box, Excel generated a new grouped field.  Excel grouped my dates automatically by month then displayed a checkbox for this new calculated field.  I would like to remove that entirely or at least to be able to change the name of that field.  Why?  This is because I have changed the headers (column names) for my data after creating this pivot table.  As a result, when I refresh my data, the refresh fails because this grouped field Excel created no longer exists in my Data source.

Right click the field and choose Ungroup. You can also turn off default date grouping in pivot tables in Excel options.

@Rory, that does not work because this grouping was automatically generated by Excel.  I have found  solution using Power Pivot to access stubborn, hidden and system fields.

You need to select one of the actual dates, not a header, then ungroup.

I cannot ungroup as the field I wish to remove, the date[months] field was calculated by the system. I discovered that  I could use Power Pivot to access that column (or indeed, any stubborn, hidden or system created field) and delete it that way.  Using Power Pivot is the only way to access system and hidden fields for administration purposes such as renaming or deleting them.
